# Weird - third @PathVariable not working in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a weird problem with implementing a REST call in Spring. I have implemented the following URL structure with three @PathVariables in there.

```
GET http://server/module/api/P1/P1-Value/P2/P2-Value/P3/P3-Value
```

Looks very simple to me, but Spring throws a NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException exception and calls my handleInvalidRequests method. After some investigation, I found that changing the last PathVariable to a RequestParam works (while keeping everything else the same).

```
http://server/module/api/P1/P1-Value/P2/P2-Value?P3=P3-Value
```

I cannot believe it but the only explanation I have is it seems to be a bug in the Spring framework. Is anyone else facing a similar problem? And more importantly is there anything else I can try to debug it to get it working?

***PS:*** The closest issue on Spring's Jira I found was https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5365 which is not reproducible for them. Maybe I have hit it! In case anyone from Spring wants to work on this I will be happy to provide the details.

Comment: You will need to show the Spring Controller that you expect to handle the request

Comment: Can you post your source code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is related to [SPR-11550](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11550).
Do you have a matching route that ends in `"/**"`?

If it is, its fix is scheduled for 4.1.RC1.